# Unable to register .xls as custom MIME type in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mime-types

I've updated **config/initializers/mime_types.rb** and restarted the server.

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.sealed-xls", :xls
```

My controller looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xls {  send_file(file_name, filename:  "dagsrapport.xls")  }
  format.html
end
```

This is the error I get when I do a GET on `/sheet.xls`

```
To respond to a custom format, register it as a MIME type first: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads. If you meant to 
respond to a variant like :tablet or :phone, not a custom format, be sure to nest your variant 
response within a format response: format.html { |html| html.tablet { ... } }
```

Any tips to what I'm missing? I can't see what I'm doing wrong according to the doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads

Answer (score 18):

All I did to register xls as Mime type - just added to **config/initializers/mime_types.rb** `Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls`
and **restarted the server**. Hope it'll help.

Comment: restart the server is important